# Replacing a group with svg from file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm loading a svg image from file and manipulate it with d3js. It's working fine, but now I have do do a more complicated part. There is a group in this SVG which should be replaced in two cases.

The original svg is loaded with:

```
    d3.xml('img/image.svg', "image/svg+xml",
            function (xml) {
                var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
                d3.select("#svg-image").node().appendChild(importedNode);
               //maniupulate something 
               d3.select('#text1').text(' New Text');
});
```

I' am trying to load the new svg in the same manner with:

```
    d3.xml('img/new_tiny.svg', "image/svg+xml",
                    function (xml) {
                        var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
                        // remove the old image
                        d3.select("#g3394").remove(); 
                        //append new image 
                        d3.select("#g3353").node().appendChild(importedNode);
                    });
```

But it is displaced and extra large.

**Update:** Here is the content of the group:

```
<g
i:extraneous="self"
id="g3353"
transform="translate(1286.3344,71.310647)">
<g
id="g3394"
transform="translate(-2.5610031,0)">
<g
id="g3355">
x=&quot;1306.5291&quot;
y=&quot;110.07136
<circle
style="fill:#524c48"
sodipodi:ry="9.3999996"
sodipodi:rx="9.3999996"
sodipodi:cy="63.200001"
sodipodi:cx="48"
d="M 57.4,63.200001 C 57.4,68.391477 53.191476,72.6 48,72.6 c -5.191476,0 -9.4,-4.208523 -9.4,-9.399999 0,-5.191477 4.208524,-9.4 9.4,-9.4 5.191476,0 9.4,4.208523 9.4,9.4 z"
id="circle3357"
r="9.3999996"
cy="63.200001"
cx="48" /><path
style="fill:#ff6600"
inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
id="path3359"
d="m 48,75.3 c -6.6,0 -12.1,-5.4 -12.1,-12.1 0,-6.7 5.4,-12 12.1,-12 6.7,0 12,5.4 12,12 0,6.6 -5.4,12.1 -12,12.1 z m 0,-18.8 c -3.7,0 -6.7,3 -6.7,6.7 0,3.7 3,6.7 6.7,6.7 3.7,0 6.7,-3 6.7,-6.7 0,-3.7 -3,-6.7 -6.7,-6.7 z" /></g><g
id="g3361"><circle
style="fill:#524c48"
sodipodi:ry="9.3999996"
sodipodi:rx="9.3999996"
sodipodi:cy="63.200001"
sodipodi:cx="160.5"
d="m 169.9,63.200001 c 0,5.191476 -4.20852,9.399999 -9.4,9.399999 -5.19148,0 -9.4,-4.208523 -9.4,-9.399999 0,-5.191477 4.20852,-9.4 9.4,-9.4 5.19148,0 9.4,4.208523 9.4,9.4 z"
id="circle3363"
r="9.3999996"
cy="63.200001"
cx="160.5" /><path
style="fill:#ff6600"
inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
id="path3365"
d="m 160.5,75.3 c -6.6,0 -12.1,-5.4 -12.1,-12.1 0,-6.7 5.4,-12.1 12.1,-12.1 6.7,0 12.1,5.4 12.1,12.1 0,6.7 -5.5,12.1 -12.1,12.1 z m 0,-18.8 c -3.7,0 -6.7,3 -6.7,6.7 0,3.7 3,6.7 6.7,6.7 3.7,0 6.7,-3 6.7,-6.7 0,-3.7 -3,-6.7 -6.7,-6.7 z" /></g><g
id="g3367"><path
style="fill:#ffffff"
inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
id="path3369"
d="M 126.9,64.5 H 68.5 c -0.7,0 -1.3,-0.6 -1.3,-1.3 0,-0.7 0.6,-1.3 1.3,-1.3 h 58.4 c 0.7,0 1.3,0.6 1.3,1.3 0,0.7 -0.6,1.3 -1.3,1.3 z" /><g
id="g3371"><polygon
style="fill:#ffffff"
id="polygon3373"
points="140.1,63.2 121.5,70.8 125.9,63.2 121.5,55.6 " /></g></g></g></g>
```

How can I replace a group with another svg and preserve position and size?

Comment: Copy any transforms from the old group to the new group. If that's not it, showing us g3394 and g3353 is going to be necessary otherwise were just going to be guessing.

Comment: It's worth noting, that a `<g>` doesn't have dimensions by itself. Width and height of it are determined by the content within it. If you want the group to have the same size, you have to take care of its content's size.

Comment: I've added the group content that should be replaced by similar content.
How can I get the size of this @altocumulus?